# Drawbacks to disabling SSL for functional testing purposes

Tags: automated-testing, functional, development-process, ssl

We've created an OpenLDAP docker image for local development environment and functional testing purposes. We have two protocols to choose from:

- `ldap` protocol - port 389
- `ldaps` (LDAP over SSL) protocol - port 636

From what I understand, non-secure option is easier to set up and there is no SSL impact on performance - tests may potentially be faster overall.

**What potential problems are likely if we turn the SSL off for functional testing purposes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **functional testing** I would expect to have no impact at all. The LDAP protocol is functionally identical independent of whether it is over SSL or not.

For **non-functional testing** (e.g. performance testing as you highlighted) there will potentially be some differences. You could work around this by performing your non-functional testing in an environment that does use ldaps.